# Less than in Groovy case/switch statement

Tags: groovy

I have the following switch statement

```
    switch (points) {
       case 0: name = "new"; break;
       case 1..14: badgeName = "bronze-coin"; break;
       case 15..29: badgeName = "silver-coin"; break;
       default: badgeName = "ruby";
    }
```

I'd like the first case (case 0) to include points less than or equal to 0. How can I do this in Groovy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
switch(points)
{
    case Integer.MIN_VALUE..0: badgeName = "new"; break;
    case 1..14: badgeName = "bronze-coin"; break;
    case 15..29: badgeName = "silver-coin"; break;
    default: badgeName = "ruby";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
case { it instanceof Integer && it < 0 }:
```

Comment: Doh!  Missed the first case :-/